# Where to use NULLIF inside of a CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-null

I'm getting a divide by zero error when performing the below code. I have tried a `NULLIF` after the `ELSE`, but I am encountering the same error message:

```
SELECT 
    country_IBS
    , Sku
    , LTM_Sales_USD
    , PTM_Sales_USD
    , LTM_Cost_USD
    , (CASE WHEN -([LTM_Sales_USD]-[PTM_Sales_USD])/([LTM_Sales_USD]+[PTM_Sales_USD]) IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE -([LTM_Sales_USD]-[PTM_Sales_USD])/([LTM_Sales_USD]+[PTM_Sales_USD])  END  +1)/2 AS "Sales Growth % (scaled)"  
FROM #tempSalesChange
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the divider in the `NULLIF`:

```
{Expression 1} / NULLIF({Expression 2},0)
```

That will mean that if the divider is `0` then `NULL` will be returned, and the divide by zero error will be avoided.

In your case, that's `([LTM_Sales_USD]+[PTM_Sales_USD])`.

Answer (score 3):

If suspect that you want:

```
(1 - ([LTM_Sales_USD] - [PTM_Sales_USD]) / NULLIF([LTM_Sales_USD] + [PTM_Sales_USD], 0) 
) / 2 AS [Sales Growth % (scaled)]
```

That is: the divisor should be wrap in `NULLIF(..., 0)`. This avoids the division by zero error - in that case, the whole computation returns `NULL` instead.